# dataframes manipulation and merging python

Tags: python, pandas

```
  I have a dataframe,df1 

        inp   aco   drtn                
      2.3.6  dp   Less than 1 min         
      2.3.6  ft   5-10 min        
      2.5.9  dp   More than 1 hour        
      0.8.0  dp    1-5 min                
      2.3.6  dp   10-30 min               
      2.3.6  dp   More than 1 hour        
      0.8.0  dp   Less than 1 min         
      0.8.0  dp   1-5 min
```

df1 should be grouped by the 3 columns by counting the occurrences. The new dataframe,df2 will look like this:

```
       inp   aco   drtn                count
      2.3.6  dp   Less than 1 min         1
      2.3.6  ft   5-10 min                1
      2.5.9  dp   More than 1 hour        1
      0.8.0  dp    1-5 min                2
      2.3.6  dp   10-30 min               1
      2.3.6  dp   More than 1 hour        1
      6.2.6  dp   1-5 min                 1
```

the column: 'drtn' should be converted into a new column:'convrt'.
This convrt column, for example will look like: less than 1 min=0.59minute, more than 1 hour=61 minutes, 1-5 min= 5 minutes,5-10 min=10, 10-30 min=30 minutes. Another new column:'calc' should be defined as the value of the 'count' column multiplied by the value in column: 'convrt' .Then a new dataframe,df3 should look like this:

```
       inp   aco   drtn                 count   convrt   calc
      2.3.6  dp   Less than 1 min         1     0.59     0.59
      2.3.6  ft   5-10 min                1      10      10
      2.5.9  dp   More than 1 hour        1      61      61
      0.8.0  dp    1-5 min                2       5      10
      2.3.6  dp   10-30 min               1      30      30
      2.3.6  dp   More than 1 hour        1      61      61
      6.2.6  dp   1-5 min                 1       5       5
```

then a new dataframe,df4 that is filtered by the column:'aco'. for example:only values having dp should only be retained. then a new column:pct that computes percentage of changes in column:'calc'.

```
       inp   aco   drtn                 count   convrt   calc   pct
      2.3.6  dp   Less than 1 min         1     0.59     0.59   0.003
      2.5.9  dp   More than 1 hour        1      61      61     36.40
      0.8.0  dp    1-5 min                2       5      10     0.060
      2.3.6  dp   10-30 min               1      30      30     17.90 
      2.3.6  dp   More than 1 hour        1      61      61     36.40
      6.2.6  dp   1-5 min                 1       5       5     0.030
```

then a new dataframe,df5 with a new column:'pct' which adds all the values in the column:'calc' of df3 and also in the column:'calc' of df4 and proceeds to divide(df4/df3) and multiply by 100 with the index named as the filtered value of column:'aco'. Then, a new column 'totalCalcFilteredColumn' gets the total sum of the column:'calc' in filtered dataframe,df4.
Another column named:'diff' which adds all the values in the column:'calc' of df3 and also in the column:'calc' of df4, then proceeds to do subtraction(df3-df4)

```
        pctTime      totalCalcFilteredColumn     diff    
  dp    94.37         167.59                     10        
  ft    5.63           10                       167.59
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: Oh man, this is tantamount to asking someone to do your entire project for you. Please ask _separate_ questions, this is _wayyyy_ beyond SO's scope.

Comment: No headway! I have been on this for a while!

Comment: Like I said. One question at a time. You have 3-4 of them. Take out all but the first now. Then, open another question, and ask the next part... and so on.

Comment: Did you do some search? Why not start with googling? You are very clear what you want for each step. Turn it into English and search, buddy. For example, "grouped by the 3 columns by counting the occurrences" can turn into googling """grouped by columns and count the occurrences"""

Comment: @Tai I actually did! my first bottleneck was this:`df=pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['inp','aco','drtn'])`

     `df=df .groupby(['inp'])['aco'].value_counts().sort_values  (ascending=False).reset_index(name='count') `

Comment: @Bode Cool. so that you want to group by 3 columns and you only pass in one column name in groupby? Don't just post data. Also post your code to let us know how to help you correctly. Also, post your data with `to_dict()` function.

Comment: @Tai My bad! working already! How do I go about  converting the 'drtn' column in df3 to 'convrt' column in df3?

Comment: @Bode Search build a column based on conditions in other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```
temp=u"""inp;aco;drtn
2.3.6;dp;Less than 1 min
2.3.6;ft;5-10 min
2.5.9;dp;More than 1 hour
0.8.0;dp;1-5 min
2.3.6;dp;10-30 min
2.3.6;dp;More than 1 hour
0.8.0;dp;1-5 min
6.2.6;dp;1-5 min"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep=";")
print (df)
     inp aco              drtn
0  2.3.6  dp   Less than 1 min
1  2.3.6  ft          5-10 min
2  2.5.9  dp  More than 1 hour
3  0.8.0  dp           1-5 min
4  2.3.6  dp         10-30 min
5  2.3.6  dp  More than 1 hour
6  0.8.0  dp           1-5 min
7  6.2.6  dp           1-5 min
```

Solution:

```
d = {'1-5 min': 5, '10-30 min': 30, '5-10 min': 10,
'Less than 1 min': 0.59, 'More than 1 hour': 61}

df = df.groupby(['inp', 'aco', 'drtn'], sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count')
#map column by dictionary
df['convrt'] = df['drtn'].map(d)
df['calc'] = df['convrt'].mul(df['count'])
#divide by groups - transform create Series with same size as original df
df['pct'] = df['calc'].div(df.groupby('aco')['calc'].transform('sum')).mul(100)
print (df)
     inp aco              drtn  count  convrt   calc         pct
0  2.3.6  dp   Less than 1 min      1    0.59   0.59    0.352050
1  2.3.6  ft          5-10 min      1   10.00  10.00  100.000000
2  2.5.9  dp  More than 1 hour      1   61.00  61.00   36.398353
3  0.8.0  dp           1-5 min      2    5.00  10.00    5.966943
4  2.3.6  dp         10-30 min      1   30.00  30.00   17.900829
5  2.3.6  dp  More than 1 hour      1   61.00  61.00   36.398353
6  6.2.6  dp           1-5 min      1    5.00   5.00    2.983472
```

---

```
#aggregate sum 
df = df.groupby('aco')['calc'].sum().reset_index(name='totalCalcFilteredColumn')
summed = df['totalCalcFilteredColumn'].sum()
df['pctTime'] = df['totalCalcFilteredColumn'].div(summed).mul(100)
#rsub means sub from right  summed - df['calc']
df['diff'] = df['totalCalcFilteredColumn'].rsub(summed)
print (df)
  aco  totalCalcFilteredColumn    pctTime    diff
0  dp                   167.59  94.369052   10.00
1  ft                    10.00   5.630948  167.59
```